# index.html:114 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I' m working with the ethereum blockchain, I wrote the contract in solidity and now I' m on the Front-End part of the application. I copyed the code for 'WEB3DEPLOY'...

```
        var dapp = dappContract.new(
      _acconto,
      _saldo,
      _technician,
      _Time, {
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
        data: '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',
        gas: '4700000'
      },
      function(e, contract) {
        console.log(e, contract);
        if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') { //ERROR AT THIS LINE
          console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
          CAddress = contract.address;
        }
      })
```

When I run the application it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
```

Console Outpout of the error:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
at Object.InvalidResponse (web3.min.js:1)
at web3.min.js:1
at XMLHttpRequest.r.onreadystatechange (web3.min.js:1) undefined
```

I don' t know how to resolve the problem, sorry for bad English.

Comment: What does the `console.log(e, contract)` line output? It looks like your contract deployment is failing and `e` is likely non-null.

Comment: @AdamKipnis I updated the problem with the console log... Sorry for the bad writing of the question.

Comment: I updated the testrpc but nothing changed

Comment: The output confirms my previous comment. The error is being thrown from your smart contract constructor, not the client side.

Comment: @AdamKipnis I found the error... The contract revert (as in remix) when there is not enough ether included in the transaction. I don' t know how its called but it is the msg.value... Now, how can I add this value to the contract.new() function? I didn' t find anything significant in the documentatio or in the internet.

Comment: Ether is sent to the contract with the `value` option in the transaction object (value is in Wei). See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#parameters-25.